# onCreate() workflow confusion

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am trying to develop an android app. I have used [this](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/) tutorial. MainActivity code is as below

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // withholding the previously created fragment from being created again
            // On orientation change, it will prevent fragment recreation
            // its necessary to reserve the fragment stack inside each tab
            initScreen();

        } else {
            // restoring the previously created fragment
            // and getting the reference
            carouselFragment = (CarouselFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
        }
    }
```

As I understand, the line that checks the savedInstanceState is null or not, we are trying to save the user current screen. I think, it covers the possibility of pressing the home button and reopening app and rotating the screen. But in the current situation, onCreate is not called when applciation is reopened. But I went through android workflow in the following [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc), it doesn't accept to call onCreate() again. But we are using the savedInstanceState as a parameter which is used to check it has a previous state or not as understand. To sum up, I get confused the usage of savedInstanceState. If it is used to check previous state then why onCreate is not called?

EDITED : As the comments explain, reopening the app doesnt cause recreation. As I know onStart() is called. How can I check savedState in onStart to recreate the views or storing previous fragment?

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState is the magic function which solves you confusion

Comment: I know there is a function like that, but i will not use any stored parameter. I just confused about the explained and referred usages.

Comment: onCreate is called when the activity is freshly created. When the application is reopened, it is restarted, not recreated, which means your activity is still there. When you rotate your phone, the activity is destroyed and recreated in the new configuration, so then onCreate is called

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrongly know when reopen app, its recreated again. Is there any recreation scenarios like rotating?

Answer (score 0):

The different states with their corresponding callbacks are:

`onCreate` ->`created` The activity is created,  but not yet running or not visible anymore.

`onStart`  ->`started` The activity is started, but not yet running or out of focus.

`onResume` -> `resumed` The activity is running.

`onPause` -> `paused` The activity is paused, because it lost focus/is not the foreground activity.

`onStop` -> `stopped` The activity is stopped, because it is not visible anymore.

`onDestroy` -> `destroyed` The activity is destroyed, because it is finished, e.g. because there was an orientation change, or it is being destroyed by the system for memory.

In you example, when going to the home screen, the activity is being stopped, but not destroyed, so when returning to the app, `onCreate` is not called.

When rotating your phone, the current activity cannot be used, because it has the wrong orientation, so it is destroyed and a new activity is created. In this case, `onCreate` is called.

For nice diagrams of this, see the Android developers [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc) on the activity lifecycle.

Generally, you do not need `savedInstanceState` when your activity is just stopped, because your activity will retain its state. If you do want to use `savedInstanceState` when stopped, use `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`. It is called after `onStart()`.

Some more detailed information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` is called when you change the orientation in the openend app. In the `savedInstanceState`can it find some informations to the state the Activity had before the orientation change. I has nothing to do with reopening the app.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, when dealing with methods within an application, make sure you understand what each line does... For example:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This means you are creating a super class within the method. Understand what you are calling.